# Spring Boot problem with JUnit execution test

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I have the problem with running Junit test, I have error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
```

How I see, Spring Boot can not find my test Class. I have multiple maven modules, in my `A` module I have `SpringBootApplication` class and controllers and in module `B` I have my Service module were I wrote my Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass{

    @Autowired
    private ImplDatabase serviceDatabase;

    @MockBean
    private Repository repository;

    @Test
    public void saveMethode() {
        Model model= new Model ();

        event.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        model.setMessage("sdsd");
        model.setCategory("Somi");

        when(repository.save(model)).thenReturn(model);
        assertEquals(model, serviceDatabase.saveTest(model));
    }

}
```

And I have `C` module where is stored my `Repository`.

Hierarchy of dependency is:  I have dependency in `A` module for `B` and `C`, and in `B` module I have dependency for `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In module `B` you can create

```
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.myapp.moduleB",
                "com.mycompany.myapp.moduleB.subpackage1",
                "com.mycompany.myapp.moduleB.subpackage1.subsubpackage1a",
                "com.mycompany.myapp.moduleB.subpackage2"
                 /*add here all required packages to scan for B's components and services*/ })
public class BConfig {}
```

and then mark Junit test in module B with `@SpringBootTest(classes = BConfig.class)`

**Note, `BConfig` does not have to be in main sources, place it in test sources**

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggest that you need you specify your application context class b/c spring cannot find it:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// Application is the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}) 
public class TestClass {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I have a problem, I can not import package for  `Application.class`, my `B` can not recognize my `A` module. How I said my test class is in my `B` module.

Comment: If you want to unit test your services in module B then you should not have a dependency on module A and you should mock any dependencies external to module B. If you want to perform integration test with components of module A then you should write your test in module A, not in module B. Hope that helps.